# The probability that the number of successful of Bernoulli experiments are always close to their mean

Tags: probability

Given an infinite series of Bernoulli experiments, with probability p for the success of each, I wish to show that for every $p'<p$, the probability that at any point in the sequence more than $p'$ of the tests were successful is positive.

I am not entirely certain this theorem holds, but it feels intuitively true to me, yet I haven't found a way to prove it.

Comment: The title does not describe the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At each time $n$, add $1-p'$ if the $n$th test is succesful, and $-p'$ otherwise. Call $X_n$ the position after $n$ steps. Since each test is succesful with probability $p$, the process $(X_n)$ performs a random walk with drift (the mean displacement) $(1-p')p+(-p')(1-p)=p-p'$. This drift is positive hence the probability that $X_n\gt0$ for every $n\geqslant1$ is positive.

---

**Example:** Assume that $p'=\frac13\lt p$, then $Y_n=3X_n$ is a $+2/-1$ random walk. Let $t_i$ denote the probability that $(Y_n)$ hits $0$ starting from $i$, then the probability that $X_n\gt0$ for every $n\geqslant1$ is $z=p\cdot(1-t_2)$.

Furthermore, the Markov property after one step of the random walk shows that $(t_i)$ solves the system $t_0=1$, $t_i=pt_{i+2}+qt_{i-1}$ for every $i\geqslant1$, where $q=1-p$.

Thus $t_i=ar^i+bs^i+ct^i$ for some $(a,b,c)$, where $(r,s,t)$ solve the characteristic equation $x=px^3+q$. Thus, $t=1$ and $(r,s)$ solve $px^2+px=q$, that is, $s=-\frac12-\frac12\sqrt{1+4q/p}$ and $r=-\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{1+4q/p}$, hence $s\lt-1$ and $0\lt r\lt1$.

*One knows that* $t_i\to0$ when $i\to\infty$ hence $b=c=0$ and $t_i=r^i$ for every $i\geqslant0$. In particular, $z=p(1-r^2)=\frac32p-1+\frac12p\sqrt{1+4q/p}$.

*Sanity checks:* $z\to1$ when $p\to1$ (*why?*), $z\to0$ when $p\to\frac13$ (*why?*), and $z$ is a nondecreasing function of $p$ (*why?*).

Comment: Your random walk argument is excellent. But I was thinking can we prove it just by calculating the probability explicitly and showing that it is positive?

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay When $p'=a/b$ is rational the probability $u$ to stay positive for ever solves a polynomial equation of degree $b$ hence what you suggest is possible in principle--except that $1$ always solves said polynomial equation hence, to decide that $u$ is another root one must know that $u\ne1$ by another argument. If $p'$ is irrational, this approach fails even before that since the random walk lives on a dense subset of the real line.

Comment: The probability $u$ is going to be $\sum_{k=\lceil{np'}\rceil}^{n}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ right? Kindly correct me if I have got the whole thing wrong.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay Why do you think so? I see no reason why and this contradicts the solvable cases.

Comment: That's why I was a little confused about this question, I thought the question asks to show that the probability I have written is positive for all $n$. Maybe I understood it wrong. Please tell me the correct one.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay Please compare your beliefs with the case fully solved at the end of my post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9843/discussion-between-samrat-mukhopadhyay-and-did)

Comment: Thanks. I really liked the proof.